# Why GitLab "fatal: Could not read from remote repository." with push while I can make pulls?

Tags: git, gitlab

When try to `git push` I got the following message:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I can *clone* and *pull* from the remote. The remote is a GitLab private repo, so I must be authenticated to *clone* or *pull* so I suppose that key/auth problems can be discarded.

I'm on GitLab 5.2.1

**EDIT**

Just to add more info...

That error happen just after a successful `git clone` on the cloned repo. Is not really rare??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After do tons of tests like removing and adding the ssh key, unprotect all the repo branches, etc, problem get solved with a GitLab server restart.